# printf statment doesnt print the answer of built-in function when called in the printf statement. Why?

Tags: c, function, printf

I am trying to use the `pow()` bult-in function directly in `printf()` method and it is not working and giving me `0` result. However when I first store the answer of this function in some variable and then put the variable in `printf` method to print, it works fine. Why is that?

This program is malfunctioning.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <conio.h>
void main(void)
{
    int a=5;
    clrscr();
    printf("%d",pow(a,2));
    getch();
}
```

While the below one runs perfect.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <conio.h>
void main(void)
{
    int a=5;
    clrscr();
    a=pow(a,2);
    printf("%d",a);
    getch();
}
```

Comment: What does `pow()` return?

Comment: Additionally, a**void** writing **void** `main(void)`; use `int main(void)` instead.

Comment: @machine_1  I have mentioned that when I use this function in print command, it is giving me 0 answer. While in the later code, it gives me 25 as expected.

Comment: I am not asking you about the output. I am asking you about the return value of the function `pow()`, to make you realize that you are using an incorrect format specifier to print the return value of `pow()` function.

Comment: @machine_1 it returns double I believe? I just read on internet

Comment: Good, then now you know the type of the return value of `pow()`, use the appropriate format specifier `"%f"` in `printf()` to print it correctly.

Comment: @machine_1 thank you so much